# The approximation of a function of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the approximation of the following function :
$$ \det(({\mathbf A}+ \epsilon {\mathbf B})^H({\mathbf A}+ \epsilon {\mathbf B}))$$
when $\epsilon <<1$ ?

(Note that ${\mathbf A}$ and ${\mathbf B}$ are $M \times N $ matrices.)

Comment: It's a polynomial in $\epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, but its behavior at small $\epsilon$ is important for me.

Comment: So how to comprehend "Taylor series"? It makes no difference on a polynomial. Do you mean you want certain coefficients?

Comment: I changed the title according to your comment. You are right the approximation may not need the tylor series. I thought the Taylor series may help.

Comment: And $\det(P^HP)=|\det(P)|^2$. Please detail your goal of approximation, or tell us the original question in order that we know what to do.

Comment: One way: you can use Weyl's inequality for eigenvalue perturbations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl's_inequality

Comment: Indeed, the matrices ${\mathbf A}$ and ${\mathbf B}$ are random matrices with wishart distribution. I have to take expectation over them. The expectation problem will be a very hard problem unless I can approximate the function. We know that $\epsilon$ is small$. @WildChan

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi's_formula might be a useful first-order approximation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assumming that $M^H$ is the hermitian conjugate. You can rewrite the function you want as: 
(ignoring second order terms but it should not be too hard to find the second order approximation following this method) $\det(A^HA + \epsilon M)$ where $M =B^H A + A^H B $ next you may use the formula for the determinant involving the Levi-Civita symbol:

$$\det X = \varepsilon_{i_1 \cdots i_n}X_{i_1 1} \cdots X_{i_n n}$$

and substitute $X = A^H A + \epsilon M$. To first order the result is that the function you want is

$$\det(A^H A) + \epsilon \sum_{k=1}^n \det A_k $$
here $A_k$ is the matrix obtained by replacing the $k$-th column of $A^H A$ by the $k$-th column of $M$. Hopefully this may be of some help.